# Prove that if k and j are relatively prime to n, then so is k * j modulo n

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

**GCD(kj, n) = 1** as **kj** and **n** don't share common prime factors.

**kj=qn + r** for some **q**

let's construct linear combinations

ks + nt = 1

ju + nv = 1

Multiplying left-hand and right-hand sides

**(kj)** su + ksnv + ntju + ntnv = 1

**(qn+r)** su + ksnv + ntju + ntnv = 1

rsu + qnsu + ksnv + ntju + ntnv = 1

**r**(su) + **n**(qsu + ksv + tju + tnv) = 1

This shows that there exists such linear combination of r and n that is equal to 1.

Proof completed.

Is it sound and rigorous proof?

Comment: You can use prime factors in the second part. If the prime $p$ divides $r$ and $n$ it divides $kj$. so divides (at least one of) $k$ or $j$, contradicting the fact $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime, as are $j$ and $n$.  The Bezout Theorem argument that you have in mind will work, but is not well expressed. *Start* from the assertion that there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $kjx+ny=1$. Or better start from $ks+nt=1$, $ju+nv=1$.

Comment: How can the linear combination of $kj$ and $n$ be $1$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. I edited my proof.

Comment: Pretty good now. However, the first line is now superfluous, you no longer need to invoke unique factorization. You should explain more what you are doing. "Since $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime, by Bezout's Theorem there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $ks+nt=1$. Similarly,  $\dots$." What you write should reflect what you know. Too many equations, too little text.